# ReadConsoleOutput, WriteConsoleOutput, ReadConsoleInput functionality in Mono under Linux

Tags: .net, winapi, mono, console, pinvoke

I use in .Net version of my program three native WinApi functions through P/Invoke:
[ReadConsoleOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684965(VS.85).aspx), [WriteConsoleOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687404(VS.85).aspx), [ReadConsoleInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684961(VS.85).aspx).
How to implement this functionality in Mono counterpart under Linux?

I know about standart System.Console class. But this class for some strange reason does not support functionality of previously mentioned winapi-functions in any way.

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite your I/O so that it keeps track of what ought to be on the screen itself (which shouldn't take up too much memory these days), and only update using the `Console` class, you should find that Mono's implementation can keep up. Mono also comes with access to ncurses functionality via the [`Mono.Terminal` namespace](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/monodoc.ashx?link=N%3aMono.Terminal), but sticking to `Console` will be more portable. You can still use it for positioning and color, via `SetCursorPosition` method, `BackgroundColor` property, etc.

Comment: Actually, I haven't seen any console thing which worked differently on Mono.

Answer (score 0):

For functionality equivalent for ReadConsoleInput use can use [libtermkey](http://www.leonerd.org.uk/code/libtermkey/) library.

ReadConsoleOutput is impossible in Linux, but you can store the data in custom screen buffer. WriteConsoleOutput can be easy implemented using [NCurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Look at the event loop implemented in Windows and Posix platforms. Main functions used are: poll(), pipe(), writeInt64(), readInt64() - from standard libc:

```
termkeyHandle = LibTermKey.termkey_new( 0, TermKeyFlag.TERMKEY_FLAG_SPACESYMBOL );

// Setup the input mode
Console.Write( "\x1B[?1002h" );
pollfd fd = new pollfd( );
fd.fd = 0;
fd.events = POLL_EVENTS.POLLIN;

pollfd[ ] fds = new pollfd[ 2 ];
fds[ 0 ] = fd;
fds[ 1 ] = new pollfd( );
int pipeResult = Libc.pipe( pipeFds );
if ( pipeResult == -1 ) {
    throw new InvalidOperationException( "Cannot create self-pipe." );
}
fds[ 1 ].fd = pipeFds[ 0 ];
fds[ 1 ].events = POLL_EVENTS.POLLIN;

while ( true ) {
    int pollRes = Libc.poll( fds, 2, -1 );
    if ( pollRes == 0 ) throw new InvalidOperationException( "Assertion failed." );
    if ( pollRes == -1 ) {
        int errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if ( errorCode != Libc.EINTR ) {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format("poll() returned with error code {0}", errorCode));
        }
    }

    bool needProcessInvokeActions = false;
    if ( fds[ 1 ].revents != POLL_EVENTS.NONE ) {
        UInt64 u;
        Libc.readInt64( fds[ 1 ].fd, out u );
        if ( u == 1 ) {
            // Exit from application
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( ( fds[ 0 ].revents & POLL_EVENTS.POLLIN ) == POLL_EVENTS.POLLIN ||
         ( fds[ 0 ].revents & POLL_EVENTS.POLLHUP ) == POLL_EVENTS.POLLHUP ||
         ( fds[ 0 ].revents & POLL_EVENTS.POLLERR ) == POLL_EVENTS.POLLERR ) {
        LibTermKey.termkey_advisereadable( termkeyHandle );
    }

    while ( ( LibTermKey.termkey_getkey( termkeyHandle, ref key ) ) == TermKeyResult.TERMKEY_RES_KEY ) {
        processLinuxInput( key );
    }

    renderer.UpdateRender( );
}
```